# rake version error when deploying with capistriano: cap shell differs from ssh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, capistrano, dreamhost

I'm deploying my new Rails application to my hosting (Dreamhost).
I'm using Capistrano for the deployment.

I'm runned 
`cap deploy`
with no problems

When I've tried to run cap deploy:migrations I recieve the following error:
Could not find rake-10.0.3 in any of the sources

To check what is happening, I've used

```
cap shell
    which rake
    --> /home/myUser/.gems/bin/rake
    /home/myUser/.gems/bin/rake -V
    --> rake, version 0.8.7
```

However, when I check the same info from ssh i get

```
$ which rake
-->/home/myuser/.gems/bin/rake
$ /home/myuser/.gems/bin/rake -V
-->rake, version 10.0.3
```

How is it possible that I get those two different results? 
Any idea?

In case it helps, I add my deploy.rb file:

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :user, 'XXX'
set :domain, 'XXX'
set :application, 'XXX'
set :repository,  "git@bitbucket.org:XXX"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/XXX"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :scm, 'git'
set :branch, 'master'
set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :scm_verbose, true
set :use_sudo, false


default_environment["PATH"] = "/home/myUser/.gems/bin:$PATH"
set :shell, '/bin/bash'

server domain, :app, :web
role :db, domain, :primary => true

set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }

namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

There was a problem of GEM_PATH, where my specific gems where not loaded.

Following added to deploy.rb

default_environment["GEM_PATH"] ="/home/myUser/.gems:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"
default_environment["PATH"] = "/home/myUser/.gems/bin:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/:$PATH"

Answer (score 0):

May be rake 0.8 is set in your Gemfile. 
And rake 10.0 is last installed version.

Comment: No, its set to 10.0.3 in the gemfile.lock. Also added it to gemfile without success.